# Android: Expandable Navigation Drawer with custom row views

Tags: android, navigation, view, adapter, drawer

I'm trying to do a navigation drawer menu with expandable elements like this --> http://goo.gl/SkMU8N

I had no idea so I started by doing something like this one (not mine).

https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest

The problem is that those rows are simple text and they looks horrible.

I want to know how to modify the Adapter (or whatever) to attach my own xml files like you do with the normal drawer (example here --> http://goo.gl/phAJy).

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done --> http://goo.gl/KPmxbL

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of slide list item 
https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with navigation drawer. 
All you have to so is find some tutorial how to create an expandable ListView because Navigation Drawer is just a ViewGroup which can contain any view.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest

This URL project doesn't have separate layout for list_view with menu & sub menu. That's why we are unable to edit the code.

Is there any code with separate layout for menu/sub menu. Also if you anyone know horizontal sub menu. Please provide the link.