# Sub Menu in App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-menu

Is having a sub menu possible in Android?

And what do you call this view in Android?

[image: submenu]

Comment: See [What is this side menu called that can be found in many multi-touch apps, and where does it originate from?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh) on UX.SE

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this is an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), within a [`NavigationDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). There are several tutorials you can use (see my list below).

One piece of advice based on personal experience: the baseline behavior for the [`SimpleExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) is pretty limiting and often not what you're looking for in your customization. If you're looking to have your own specific behavior and look-and-feel to the sub menus, I highly recommend looking into extending the [`BaseExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html) yourself and creating your own custom adapter. [This may seem daunting at first, but it's not terribly hard once you have a grasp on your parents and children within your menu and sub menu(s).]

- Fantastic example project creating custom adapter: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView
- Another article here discussing this: [Android: Expandable Navigation Drawer with custom row views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496843/android-expandable-navigation-drawer-with-custom-row-views)
- Example `ExpandableListAdapter` (for better understanding if creating your own): http://blog.denevell.org/android-SimpleExpandableListAdapter-example.html
- Creating your own `ExpandableListAdapter`: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample code for this 
https://github.com/D8thReaper/android-navigation-menu-expandable.
The sample is in material design and is pretty simple to use.

[image: Screenshot]

In the drawer layout, use a simple ExpandableListView and customize it.

```
<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:divider="@color/list_divider"
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
android:background="@color/list_background" />
```

Make a custom adapter by extending with BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
public class NavAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{...}
```

And attach the drawerList (ExpandableListView object) to ActionBarToggle

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close )
```

Answer (score 0):

That menu called `Navigation drawer`... Check this  [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) it will guide you. The below link also will guide you...

[NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: How about the SubMenu? I Have already tried the sliding drawer. what i want to try is the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).